# Initializing a class with hash

Tags: ruby

I am defining a class whose constructor takes a single param that is hash and may have 20-30 key:values. And for all those keys, I don't want to create separate instance variables. Rather, want to keep everything in `@filter` and use it wherever I want in that class.

```
class Card
  attr_accessor :filter 

  def new (f = {})
    @filter = f
  end

  def say_hello
    "Hello #{@filter[:xyz]}"
  end
end
```

When I try to instantiate an object of this class as follows,

```
c = Card.new ({a: :b, c: :d, xyz: :klm})
```

then I get an error

```
undefined method `a=' for #<Card:0x007fafb1cc51d8>
```

What mistake am I making?

Comment: Arup, what explicitly are you asking? I have put up my code in the question. What else are you want to know?

Comment: `new` -> `initialize`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found out.

`def new (f = {})` should be `def initialize (f = {})`.